# Query Laravel Select WhereIn Array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This query does not work correctly, it only shows 1 row

```
 $data = Post::select('id', 'name')
   ->whereIn('id', [$order])
   ->orderByRaw(\DB::raw("FIELD(id, $order)"))
   ->get();
```

but this works fine, it shows all rows

```
  $data = Post::select('id', 'name')
    ->whereIn('id', [1,2,3])
    ->orderByRaw(\DB::raw("FIELD(id, $order)"))
    ->get();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your Query is Here:-

```
$data = Post::select('id', 'name')
  ->whereIn('id', $order)
  ->orderByRaw(\DB::raw("FIELD(id, ".implode(",",$order).")"))
  ->get();
```

Remove `[]` from `$order`.

For `WhereIn` condition second parameter should be an array. So the `$order` should be

```
$order = [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: This's my code $keys=array_keys($request->all());
        $order=join(", ",$keys);

Comment: Use only this  $order= array_values($request->all()); and (\DB::raw("FIELD(id, ".implode(",", $order).")")

Comment: use like this $order = array_values($request->all()) and \DB::raw("FIELD(id, ".implode(",", $order).")")

Comment: can u write o/t of $request->all() so we can debug.

Comment: Array ( [2] => 1 [3] => 4 [4] => 2 )

Comment: you need to search for [2,3,4] or [1,4,2] ?

Comment: I need get variable from post to array.

Comment: Can you write your query with static data and execute it whether it is working or not like:-
$data = Post::select('id', 'name')->whereIn('id', [2,3,4])->orderByRaw(\DB::raw("FIELD(id, 2,3,4)"))->get();

Comment: My controller 
public function checkpost(Request $request)
    {

        $keys=array_keys($request->all());
        $order=join(", ",$keys);
        $data = Post::select('id', 'name')->whereIn('id', [$order])->orderByRaw(\DB::raw("FIELD(id, $order)"))->get();
         print_r($request->all());
    }

Comment: Use it like this
checkpost(Request $request) { $keys=array_keys($request->all()); $order=join(", ",$keys); $data = Post::select('id', 'name')->whereIn('id', $keys)->orderByRaw(\DB::raw("FIELD(id, $order)"))->get(); print_r($request->all());

Answer (score 11):

If your `$order` is an array, i think that you should do this

`whereIn('id', $order)` instead of `whereIn('id', [$order])`

P.S. In official documentation mentioned that second argument should be an array:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
             ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
             ->get();
```

Comment: come on, see my first query :|

Comment: Here $keys=array_keys($request->all());
        $order=join(", ",$keys);

Comment: Here Array ( [2] => 1 [3] => 4 [4] => 2 )

Comment: yes, i tried and had error Array to string conversion

Comment: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Comment: Ok ;)   $keys=array_keys($request->all());
        $order=join(", ",$keys);
        $data = Post::select('id', 'name')->whereIn('id', $keys)->orderByRaw(\DB::raw("FIELD(id, $order)"))->get();